# Online Hostel Management System ER Diagram

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have created an ER diagram for an online hostel management system.  Please advise me if this diagram makes sense or needs improvement.

[image: ER diagram]

Comment: The relationship between Room and RoomType should have the crows feet at the Room end.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a table "StaffHostel" which has StaffID/HostelID FKs. It should also have another field called "IsManager", which can be True/False. That is a better way to represent the Staff - Hostel relationship. Table would look like:

```
HostelID (FK)
StaffID (FK)
IsManager (True/False)
```

If this is for a Hostel, note that people often don't book Rooms, but book beds! There can be many beds in a single room (usually up to 8) with customers booking a bed in a particular room. That will complicate your design significantly.

You may want to put RoomPrice into the Room table and have a "DefaultRoomTypePrice" in the RoomType table, but that is getting into semantics. I just know from experience sometimes room can be the same type but different prices for certain reasons.

It is unclear how your Catalog table is linked to the Hostel, explain a bit more? What is a Catalog?

Otherwise looks pretty good, the only thing I can imagine you might want to do differently is to hand off the payment to another provider, storing Credit Card information is a very dangerous thing to do, leave it to the big boys who implement stringent security practices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. catalog mean subsciber hostel can have many subscriber but its optional for a subscriber to subscribe or not.

Comment: please advice me how can i handle CC information

Comment: Google "credit card payment gateway". Paypal is one used extensively, but it might not be the best. Isn't too hard to integrate into a website, lots of tutorials on the web. The first of these is for ASP, the second PHP: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152280/Online-Credit-Card-Transaction-in-ASP-NET-Using-Pa
http://jdmweb.com/how-to-easily-integrate-a-paypal-checkout-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can go for adding a table called `RoleType` to store info about the role of employee by adding one more column in `Employee` table as RoleId

Role table as with two column 

`RoleId
RoleName`

here RoleId will be Pk for `RoleType` table and and will be Fk in `Employee` table, Now you can add all the roles like Manager, Caterer etc.

Don't got your `Catalog` table,other wise looks fine.

On Credit card info, don't store it your data base you can integrate [paypal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/bizui/IntegrationHub-outside) or any other payment gateway

Comment: you can go for 

[Paypal-alternate-1](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/top-12-alternatives-paypal/)
Or
[Paypal-alternate-2](http://www.fairgroundmedia.com/paypal-alternatives)